# Apache superset Aggregation metrics are not available/selectable from the slice editor menu

Tags: scatter-plot, apache-superset

In apache superset's default widget (slice) called "Life Expectancy & Rural" Metrics Assigned to X and Y axes are selected from the ***List of Metrics*** , not from the ***List of fields***. 
[Figure1:   White ticker for Metric Selected & Gray ticker for plain column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWa1g.png)

Totally cannot see these metrics from my menu:
[Figure2: Only Plain fields are available, the only Metric available is COUNT(*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLlLj.png)
Once I try using original field and add the aggregation function straight from the slice editor menu - getting an "unhashable type: 'dict'" error

Disclaimer: I didn't alter examples database

Comment: Have you tried putting your own count(field)?

Comment: Hi Shivam - I still can see just default "COUNT" only...none of Metrics appear from the slice editor menu. Maybe I should enable it somehow?